# D3 different behavior when using method chaining

Tags: javascript, d3.js, method-chaining

I have an object that takes care of generating a d3 chart:

```
this.svg = elem
    .selectAll("svg")
    .data([{}])
    .enter()
    .append("svg")

this.axis = this.svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")

// weird block
this.axis
    .selectAll("g.axis-y")
    .data([{}])
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis-y")

this.axis
    .selectAll("g.axis-y")
    .attr("transform", "translate(100,0)")
    .call(yAxis)
```

The code in this form won't generate the `yAxis`. The fault is in the block marked with **weird block**.
If I change that one with:

```
this.axis
    .selectAll("g.axis-y")
    .data([{}])

this.axis
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis-y")
```

Then things will work. I've only split the long methods chain in two separate block. 
Shouldn't the two be equals? Someone can explain why I have these two different behaviors?

Comment: because in the first one your appending a (g) to the data > .data ().append("g") ....., the second your appending a 'g' element to the actual SVG

Comment: doesn't `selection.data()` returns the update selection? So I am appending `g` to the selection returned by `.selectAll("g.axis-y").data([{}])`. Isn't it?

Comment: What is the purpose of binding the empty object as data to the selection? Is it just a placeholder for the real data to be bound? If you have no further intention to use the empty object you might get rid off it entirely. `this.axis.append("g").attr("class", "axis-y")`will do the job unless you need the data bound.

Comment: @altocumulus it's inherited code but you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because in your first code example, you are appending to the element return from the data (which doesn't exists) whereas on the second one you are appending to the `this.axis` element which from your code is the `svg` element (`this.axis = this.svg`).

You in order to make your first example you to work you need to call `enter()` when after you call `data()` as follows:

```
this.axis
 .selectAll("g.axis-y")
 .data([{}]).enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis-y")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's correct! I guess also removing the `this.axis.selectAll("g.axis-y").data([{}])` completely from the second example would work

Comment: Possibly. Consider accepting the answer if it answered your original question

Answer (score 0):

```
this.axis
    .selectAll("g.axis-y")
    .data([{}])

this.axis
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis-y")
```

Is not the same as

```
this.axis
    .selectAll("g.axis-y")
    .data([{}])
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis-y")
```

This is the same...

```
var thisAxis = this.axis
    .selectAll("g.axis-y")
    .data([{}])

thisAxis
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis-y")
```